# How can I recursively replace a string with another in many files using bash?

Tags: bash

I need to write a script that replaces all the occurrences of a certain string to "replaceWithThisNewString" in all the files in a directory and all its sub directories.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec sed -i 's/original/replacement/g' {} \+
```

Or if your `find` doesn't support `\+`:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec sed -i 's/original/replacement/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
find /aDir -type f |xargs sed -i 's/certainString/replaceWithThisNewString/g'
```

Comment: Ḧm, if going the `xargs` route, I'd use `find .... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Using [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4) :

```
shopt -s globstar # if not already enabled
sed -i '/certainString/s/certainString/replaceWithThisNewString/g' **
```